# Change priority headings for a task with the api

Tags: api, asana

I know it's possible to create a priority headings with the api (a task ends with :).

Someone knows if it's possible to assign a priority headings to a task thanks to the api ?

Thanks,

Ludovic

Answer (score 2):

Even though this feature is not supported literally by the API, you can still use a workaround to do it.

First, get the ID of the priority heading that must be on top of your task.

Then, change the order (priority) of the task with the method "addProject" on the task's endpoint and move it right after the desired priority heading.

curl -u api_key: https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks/task_id/addProject -d "project=project_id&insert_after=priority_heading_id"

Answer (score 1):

(I work at Asana)

That is currently not supported - the API does not yet provide a way for you to reprioritize tasks or move them underneath particular priority headings.

Comment: Thank you. Any clue about an upgrade for this feature ?

Comment: I can't comment as to when this will be available, but a number of developers have requested it. This is the kind of addition we would announce, so if you follow updates on the Asana developer site you will know as soon as it's rolled out.