# asana API: how to create subtask

Tags: asana

How to create sub-task so that it added below the task with colon mark.

```
{u'id': 1637024742767L, u'name': u'Leads:'}, {u'id': 1644081849544L, u'name': u'new order'} .
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is not possible with the API. Please see: 
 [Change priority headings for a task with the api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367058/change-priority-headings-for-a-task-with-the-api) 
The answer from an Asana employee says that adding tasks relative to priority headings is not currently possible via the API.